# Get all concrete implementations of a delegate collection in C# via reflection

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, delegates, concrete

Yeah, I tried to make the title smaller, but I couldn't.

I'm very new to reflection, so I'm struggling with a problem that I don't know if it's even possible to solve.

I'll use some simple delegate example to describe it.

```
public void Main() {
    var manager = new EvManager();
    var class1 = new Class1(manager);
    var class2 = new Class2(manager);

    manager.ExecuteIt(5, 12);
    /*
    This outputs:
    In Class1 -> 17
    In Class2 -> 18
    */
}

public class EvManager {
    public delegate void SumDelegate(int a, int b);
    private SumDelegate sum;

    public void AddDelegate(SumDelegate s) {
        sum += s;
    }

    public void ExecuteIt(int a, int b) {
        sum.Invoke(a, b);
    }
}

public class Class1 {
    public Class1(EvManager m) {
        m.AddDelegate(MySum);
    }

    private void MySum(int a, int b) {
        Console.Write("In Class1 -> " + (a + b));
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    public Class2(EvManager m) {
        m.AddDelegate(MyOtherSum);
    }

    private void MyOtherSum(int a, int b){
        Console.Write("In Classe2 -> " + (a + b));
    }
}
```

Okay, that's the example. What do I want from it? I want, through the EvManager "sum" delegate property be able to access the concrete implementations of all the methods that it invokes.

This is basically what I want:

```
class EvManager {
    private SumDelegate sum;
    public void ExecuteIt(int a, int b) {
        var invocationList = sum.GetInvocationList();
        foreach (var m in invocationList) {
            // m is a reference to the annonymous call.
            // Through reflection, I want to access the concrete method name.
            // In this case, the first iteration "MySum", and the second "MyOtherSum"
            // Is this possible?

            // Like...
            // var concreteMethodName = m.GetMethod().ConcreteCallerType.GetMethod(m.GetConreteMethodName());
            // Or something like that?
        }   
    }
}
```

Hope I made my problem clear, this is killing me.

Comment: For correctness: Your code does not what you describe in the comments. The result is always 17.

Answer (score 1):

The Method property holds the information about the real method:

```
var mName = m.Method.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following method to `EvManager`:

```
public void ListDelegates()
{
    foreach (var m in sum.GetInvocationList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

Calling it will give you what you want:

```
MySum
MyOtherSum
```

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.delegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on a `Delegate` class reference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is very simple. Use the [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Check this code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

    public class EvManager
    {
        public delegate int SumDelegate(int a, int b);
        private SumDelegate sum;

        public void AddDelegate(SumDelegate s)
        {
            sum += s;
        }

        public void ExecuteIt(int a, int b)
        {
            foreach (var m in sum.GetInvocationList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}({1}, {2}) = {3}", m.Method.Name, a, b, m.DynamicInvoke(a, b));
            }

        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1(EvManager m)
        {
            m.AddDelegate(FakeSum);
        }

        public int FakeSum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a - b;
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        public Class2(EvManager m)
        {
            m.AddDelegate(RealSum);
        }

        public int RealSum(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var manager = new EvManager();
            var class1 = new Class1(manager);
            var class2 = new Class2(manager);

            manager.ExecuteIt(5, 12);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FakeSum(5, 12) = -7
RealSum(5, 12) = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `MethodInfo`of each one of your split up `delegates` through the [`Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.method(v=vs.110).aspx) `Property` of the `Delegate` which has [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
class EvManager {
    private SumDelegate sum;
    public void ExecuteIt(int a, int b) {
        var invocationList = sum.GetInvocationList();
        foreach (var m in invocationList) {
            var concreteMethodName = m.Method.Name;
        }   
    }
}
```